# Known properties of a specific class of quantum states

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing, quantum-information

Recently, I have been studying a quantum protocol for the "Hidden Matching" problem that makes use of states that can be expressed as

$|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{x_i}|i\rangle$,

where $x_i\in \{0,1\}$ and $n$ is a power of 2. Note that instead of an $n$-level system we can consider these as states of $\log_2 n$ qubits. I suspect these states to have appeared in other contexts as they are a straightforward and useful way to map an $n$ bit string into an exponentially smaller amount of qubits. Hence I am wondering: have the properties of these types of states been already extensively studied?

I am particularly interested in how the reduced density matrix of each qubit and the entanglement of the state depend on the bit values $x_i$.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you interested in multi-partite ent. or bipartite ent.? In the second case, where would the cut be? Also, if [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/7101/juan-miguel-arrazola) is also you, you can ask the moderators to merge the two accounts.

Comment: Such states appear fairly frequently in quantum information. For example, they occur in quantum fingerprinting (quant-ph/0102001). I'm sure there is a name for this particular class of states, but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: I am interested in multipartite entanglement. Also, you are right, that account is also me and I have to thank you for reminding me of this! How exactly can I contact moderators to have them merged? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

M. G. Parker and V. Rijmen have studied the quantum entanglement of binary and bipolar sequences in [arXiv:quant-ph/0107106](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0107106). I remember reading their paper long ago. They use a lot of terminology from coding theory, so now by just skimming through, I can't understand exactly what their result is, but you can have a deeper look.

Notice also that [graph states](http://www.quantiki.org/wiki/Graph_states) are a special case of your states. In particular, $\psi$ is a graph state if and only if the sequence $x$ is generated by a quadratic polynomial in GF(2).

Comment: The class of states corresponds exactly to hypergraph states, where hyper-edges correspond to controlled-controlled-...-controlled-Z gates.

Comment: @JoeFitzsimons: true. I am curious to know if anyone has ever used the name _hypergraph states_.

Comment: I'm not sure if it appears in the literature or not, but certainly I have used it and heard it used in private correspondence.

Comment: Alesssandro, thank you for your comment, this is precisely the type of connection I suspected would exist.I will definitely look at this more carefully. Also, a scholar google search of "hypergraph states" yields only 3 results, so I do not think it is a standard term in the literature.